# Reassign ownership and drop old owner in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have got a PSQL 13.6 database that was originally created by `owner_1`, and has been populated over time. For external reasons, I now need to periodically change the owner account of the database and drop the old user accounts. When I try to achieve this I get blocked because there are objects that depend on it.

I do not want to risk loosing privileges on the `manager_role` or any cascading dependencies there might be.
How can I find and transfer the objects that are still owned by `owner_1`?

**MWE:**

1. As `postgres` user: Create `owner_1`.

```
CREATE USER owner_1 WITH CREATEDB CREATEROLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'owner_password_1';
```

2. As `owner_1`: Set up the database and objects.

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
\c test_db
CREATE ROLE manager_role;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON TABLES TO manager_role;
CREATE USER manager_1 WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'manager_password_1' IN ROLE manager_role;
```

3. As `owner_1`: Create an `owner_role`, transfer ownership, and create new user in that role.

```
CREATE ROLE owner_role WITH NOLOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO owner_role;
GRANT owner_role TO "owner_1";
REASSIGN OWNED BY owner_1 TO owner_role;

CREATE USER owner_2 WITH CREATEDB CREATEROLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'owner_password_2' IN ROLE owner_role;
```

You should now have these user definitions

```
\du
                                       List of roles
  Role name   |                         Attributes                         |   Member of    
--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+----------------
 manager_1    |                                                            | {manager_role}
 manager_role | Cannot login                                               | {}
 owner_1      | Create role, Create DB                                     | {owner_role}
 owner_2      | Create role, Create DB                                     | {owner_role}
 owner_role   | Create role, Create DB, Cannot login                       | {}
 postgres     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

4. As `owner_2`: Drop the old user.

```
DROP USER owner_1;
```

This last command will fail with the error:

```
ERROR:  role "owner_1" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  owner of default privileges on new relations belonging to role owner_1 in schema public
```

**EDIT**
Executing `DROP OWNED BY owner_1;` from the `owner_2` user fails with an error:

```
test_db=> DROP OWNED BY owner_1;
ERROR:  permission denied to drop objects
```

Comment: Seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840955/postgresql-drop-role-fails-because-of-default-privileges)?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes I have but I need the altered privileges for other roles that have been assigned by `owner_1` to still exist after `owner_1` is dropped. I.e. I want to ensure that `owner_role` is the owner of any altered privileges or other objects that are blocking the user dropping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- explicitly remove the default privileges:

  ```
  ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE owner_1 IN SCHEMA public
     REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM manager_role;
  ```
- remove all objects and privileges the role owns:

  ```
  DROP OWNED BY owner_1;
  ```

Comment: But I need the manager_role to have those default privileges. And I also don't know exactly what other objects are affected. This is just an MVE, the original system is managed by alembic and has gone through multiple revisions.

Comment: But those default privileges only apply to tables created by `owner_1`. If you need them, you cannot get rid of the role.

Comment: So the tables have been reassigned ownership to `owner_role`. Even if I drop `owner_1` the tables will still exist as they are now owned by `owner_role`.

Comment: Right.Then you don't need the default privileges for `owner_1` any more and can safely do what I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, which will result in the desired state.
Instead of creating the `owner_role`, granting it to `owner_1`, reassigning the ownership etc. I can convert `owner_1` into `owner_role` which means I no longer have to drop `owner_1` and can still create a new owner user which can then be changed periodically.

**MWE:**

Perform step 1 and 2 as above.

3. As `owner_1`: Create a new user in the `owner_1` role

```
CREATE USER owner_2 WITH CREATEDB CREATEROLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'owner_password_2' IN ROLE owner_role;
```

4. As `owner_2`: Convert `owner_1` into `owner_2`

```
ALTER ROLE owner_1 RENAME TO owner_role;
ALTER ROLE owner_role WITH NOLOGIN;
```

Now `owner_2` can be used to create `owner_3` when the account needs to be changed next and as long as `owner_2` always runs commands *as* `owner_role` (`SET ROLE owner_role;`) there should be no trouble dropping `owner_2`.